# Is this a signature or a sentence that requires punctuation?

Tags: punctuation, letter-writing

Is a period needed at the closing of a greeting card that reads: "Happy holidays from John Smith and the Smith Realty family"?

Comment: How can it be a sentence when it doesn’t contain a verb?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to place a period at the end of a salutation such as you are describing.

You can see examples of Christmas cards [here](http://www.tinyprints.com/shop/holiday-cards.htm), and they have no punctuation at the end.